# DISTINCT * is not withdrawing the duplicity (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

i already done everything to remove this duplicity on the database
On selecting a checkbox on the sectio "Bairros" i utilized as Array

```
for($m=0; $m<count($_POST["bairros"]); $m++){// LOOP 1
    $pesquisar=($_POST["bairros"][$m]);
    //Copy bairros(Array) and esporte (POST)
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cadastro WHERE
    (esporte1 = '".$_POST["esportes"]."' OR
    esporte2 = '".$_POST["esportes"]."' OR
    esporte3 = '".$_POST["esportes"]."' OR
    esporte4 = '".$_POST["esportes"]."')
    AND
    (bairro1 = '".$pesquisar."' OR
    bairro2 = '".$pesquisar."' OR
    bairro3 = '".$pesquisar."' OR
    bairro4 = '".$pesquisar."')
    AND
    ativarAparecer='sim' ORDER BY nomeCompleto ASC LIMIT 20";
    $esporte= new consultar();
    $esporte->executa($query);
    //Loops  
    for($l=0; $l<$esporte->nrw; $l++){ //LOOP 2
        echo $esporte->data["nomeCompleto"]."<br />";
        $esporte->proximo();
    } //close LOOP2
} //close LOOP1
```

- Detail: this function object oriented, I believe that i'm doing something wrong at SQL or MYSQL, perhaps something is missing there.

Comment: What does your database content look like, what's the current and expected output?

Comment: Code readability and SQL injections.  Two things that probably should be researched.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
```

Stop There. `DISTINCT *` can do what? Duplicate of what? it cant do that. Give it a field name to see unique values.

For example

```
SELECT DISTINCT nomeCompleto
```

Comment: nomeCompleto using as test
But I want to check everything, so I'm using "DISTINCT *"

Comment: You can't. You cant tell database to compare each column on each row to figure out duplicates with just `DISTINCT *`

Comment: In my database is inserted into records, searching it should appear but one other appears when selecting other checkboxs

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down. The `DISTINCT` clause will return *unique sets based on the selected columns*.

Let's say you have a table:

```
a | b | c
=========
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 1 | 3
1 | 2 | 4
```

Now if you `SELECT DISTINCT a FROM table`, you would get:

```
1
```

but if you `SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM table`, you would get:

```
a | b
=====
1 | 2
1 | 1
```

That's because `{1,2}` is different from `{1,1}`, even though the `a` column is the same between those two sets.

Obviously, doing `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table` would give you the original table because it uses all three columns as a "composition" of the unique set. If we amended the table to look like this:

```
a | b | c
=========
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 1 | 3
1 | 2 | 4
1 | 2 | 3
```

Then your result of `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table` would give:

```
a | b | c
=========
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 1 | 3
1 | 2 | 4
```

because of the duplicate result set of `{1, 2, 3}`. However, since most tables have an auto-incrementing identifier as the primary key, there is almost always no difference between `SELECT *` and `SELECT DISTINCT *`.

Perhaps you're looking to `GROUP BY` a certain column?

Comment: @CledsonStefanato That's really up to how you're implementing this, which is not immediately obvious in your question and comments. Don't forget though that `GROUP BY(column1, column2, column3)` will behave the same way as `DISTINCT` where it uses all three values as a set for comparing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

How would I be using GROUP this in my script? Column that there are several equal records are this bairro, bairro2, bairro3, bairro4. Inside it is in numbers

```
bairro1 | bairro2 | bairro3 | bairro4
     14 |    14   |   15    | 27
     34 |    15   |   14    | 30
     27 |    45   |   12    | 14
```